# Can someone specifically explain the difference between -Xignore-all-space flag and the -Xignore-space-change flag

Tags: git, git-merge, git-diff

I am looking for some help from a git maestro - can someone in detail with examples explain the difference, if any, between:

```
git merge -Xignore-all-space 'HEAD@{upstream}';
```

and

```
git merge -Xignore-space-change 'HEAD@{upstream}';
```

Comment: See the difference between `-b` and `-w` in `git diff`.

Answer (score 1):

I think space change only refers to how many white spaces separate words. When you use ignore-all-space then it also includes changes in tab, and EOL format.